# Can't retrieve data from database and store into a value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am currently working on a forum project using a gridview to attached the data to the database. Using `SelectedIndexChanged`, it will redirect to another page to display the details in labels. However, I am unable to display & there isn't any specific error.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class FAQViewPost : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WingsDrinksDbContext"].ConnectionString;
    FAQ faq = null;

    string CustQuestionCategory = null;
    string CustQuestion = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FAQID = Request.QueryString["FAQID"].ToString();
        Load(FAQID);
    }

    protected void Load(string FAQID)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM [FAQ] WHERE FAQID = @FAQID ";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string[] arr = { queryStr };
        string allQueries = string.Join(";", arr);

        cmd.CommandText = allQueries;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FAQID", FAQID);

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        sqlDa.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lbl_category.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CustQuestionCategory"].ToString();
            lbl_question.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CustQuestion"].ToString();
        }

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? Are you getting value in FAQID? Can you share the code of selectedIndexChanged event? Is it event of grid view? Are you getting rows in the data table?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you are putting the SQL into an array.  You only have one statement.  Try using just:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM [FAQ] WHERE FAQID = @FAQID ";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = queryStr;
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FAQID", FAQID);
SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

sqlDa.Fill(dt);
```

I presume you have checked that the FAQ table has a record for the id you are sending?  Also life would be a bit safer if you used numeric ids.